# How do I pass arrays from Java to C++ using Swig?

Tags: java, c++, swig

I have a method in C++ that takes an array of doubles as an argument.  I'm calling this method from Java and need to pass an array of doubles.  The C++ routine reads and modifies the values of the array and I need those updated values in Java.  How do I do this?

For example, take the C++ routine:

```
void myMethod( double *values, int size ) {
    for ( int i=0; i < size; i++ ) {
        values[i] = 2*values[i];
    }
}
```

And the Java code:

```
double[] values = { 1.3, 1.1 };
myMethod(values,values.length);
System.out.println(values[0]); // prints 2.6
```

I guess a call to myMethod cannot be made like the call above... or can it?  And what is necessary in Swig to make this work.  If I cannot make a call like the one above, how do I get my values to the C++ code?

Comment: Yes, thank you very much Andy!  You understand my question and gave a very appropriate answer... I'm still in search for more answers.  I'm particularly interested in what most people do, as this situation must come up all the time.  Do most people use Swig 2?  Do most people write their own typemaps?  Both those sound like extremes to me.

Comment: If I have to copy the array into C++ manually that's fine.  If I can allocate an array in C++ and have to use special methods to access the values in Java, that's fine.  What do most people do in cases like this?

Comment: the approach above requires setItem (index, value) on each item of the array.
I can't imagine there's not a better approach, though I can't find it after hours of searching. Any clues?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use carrays.i!

See [Swig docs on carrays](http://www.swig.org/Doc1.3/Library.html#Library_carrays)

```
%include carrays.i
%array_functions( double, double_array )
```

These two lines create the following code in my module:

```
 public static SWIGTYPE_p_double new_double_array(int nelements) {
    long cPtr = SimulatorModuleJNI.new_double_array(nelements);
    return (cPtr == 0) ? null : new SWIGTYPE_p_double(cPtr, false);
  }

  public static void delete_double_array(SWIGTYPE_p_double ary) {
    SimulatorModuleJNI.delete_double_array(SWIGTYPE_p_double.getCPtr(ary));
  }

  public static double double_array_getitem(SWIGTYPE_p_double ary, int index) {
    return SimulatorModuleJNI.double_array_getitem(SWIGTYPE_p_double.getCPtr(ary), index);
  }

  public static void double_array_setitem(SWIGTYPE_p_double ary, int index, double value) {
    SimulatorModuleJNI.double_array_setitem(SWIGTYPE_p_double.getCPtr(ary), index, value);
  }
```

Which allows me to use C arrays in Java... this solves my needs and is the best solution for my problem.  Thanks everyone for your answers!

Comment: Thank you for posting an easier approach. I think you should accept your own answer. The SWIG 2.0 link for carrays is at http://www.swig.org/Doc2.0/SWIGDocumentation.html#Library_carrays.

Comment: Is this the fastest way? I'm assuming you need to call SWIGTYPE_p_double with the number of elements in your Java array, then copy each item to the new array, then perform processing in C++ on the new array, then copy each item back into the Java array. Is there any way to do direct memory access and just pass a pointer between the two languages? Or are these extra copy operations the only way to do this due to the difference in memory management between Java and Cxx?

Answer (score 1):

[SWIG typemaps](http://www.swig.org/Doc2.0/SWIGDocumentation.html#Typemaps) should allow this. The SWIG 2.0 documentation shows this [example in Python](http://www.swig.org/Doc2.0/SWIGDocumentation.html#Typemaps_nn40).

With Java, you would use JNI code inside your SWIG typemap. JNI provides methods Get/ReleaseArrayElements. I'm guessing you could get a native array in a `typemap(in)`, then release it in a `typemap(argout)`.

Another approach would be to copy your array into a std::vector, using the existing SWIG typemap in std_vector.i.

Comment: This is a great answer!  Thanks! I may use this solution.  But the first part (writing my own typemap) is complex and the second part requires Swig 2.  At the moment I believe there must be a simpler solution... and I don't mind writing some code to copy the array into C.  I'm going to update my questions... see the update at the top.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you cannot do what org.life.java suggests...

You can check out [IPC's](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication) and also Files.

Another thing you can do is to create a process by passing it the path of the exe containing the C++ code and the array as an argument. [Runtime.exec(java.lang.String, java.lang.String[])][2] should be able to do this.

[2]: http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec(java.lang.String, java.lang.String[])

Answer (score 0):

If it's just that single method, rewrite it. If you have a (much) larger C++ code base you need to port, use [JNI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Native_Interface) (or the simpler [JNA](https://github.com/twall/jna/)). This adds quite a bit of code overhead, but it is doable.

Comment: Um... that's exactly what I'm doing... using JNI because it is a large code base.  So I chose to use Swig to create the JNI wrappers... as Swig is _much_ simpler.