# SWIGTYPE pointer value assignment is slow

Tags: pointers, java-native-interface, swig, jniwrapper

I am using SWIG to wrap certain c++ code for Java through JNI.

In Java I have

```
SWIGTYPE_p_int A = new example.new_array(n);
for (int i = 0; i< n ; i++)
     example.setitem(A,i,2*i);
```

and I pass the array to C++ , but when n is large and I have to do this 1000 times, it becomes very slow ....

Is there a faster method to do this? Specifically: Is there any way to create an array in Java and pass the whole thing to c++ at once?

Thanks

Comment: You could use std_vector.i and create a function, which takes a pointer to a std::vector<int>

Comment: The first part of my answer at: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11584600/168175 should be reasonably simple to adapt to this question.

Comment: Also: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10949956/168175